# ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. in dbcall

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

This is my code; I have added transaction for command and `SqlDataAdapter`. But I'm still getting this error "ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.". I have tried to add the transaction to `SqlCommand` in multiple ways, but still get the same error.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection(connString))
{
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        var batchCommand = new SqlCommand("spname", connection, transaction);
        batchCommand.Transaction = transaction;

        batchCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int, 4, dt.Columns[0].ColumnName);

        batchCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        batchCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(batchCommand.CommandText, connection);
        adpt.UpdateCommand = batchCommand;
        adpt.InsertCommand = batchCommand;
        adpt.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
        adpt.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;

        adpt.UpdateBatchSize = 100;

        int recordsImpacted = adpt.Update(dt);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting what error? Please add it to your question verbatim.

Comment: Have you tried inserting `connection.Open();` before invoking `SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();`?

Comment: Aside... `SqlCommand` is also an `IDisposable` implementation so should be used in a `using` scope.

Comment: When I tried to add connection.Open(); it is throwing The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with using scope also. but still same error. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try same the example:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SqlCommand batchCommand = new SqlCommand("spname", connection, transaction))
            {
                try
                {
                     batchCommand.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int, 4, dt.Columns[0].ColumnName);

                     batchCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     batchCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                     SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(batchCommand.CommandText, connection);
                     adpt.UpdateCommand = batchCommand;
                     adpt.InsertCommand = batchCommand;
                     adpt.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                     adpt.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                     adpt.UpdateBatchSize = 100;

                    int recordsImpacted = adpt.Update(dt);
                    batchCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried tihs but didnt work.

Comment: What's exception that you saw?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.

Comment: You can try add a new line code as below: `batchCommand.Transaction = transaction;` under **"try {"** block.

Comment: if still an error, add a transaction param in this code: `SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(batchCommand.CommandText, connection);` to `SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(batchCommand.CommandText, connection, transaction);`